# Google Custom Search results opening in popup on page

Tags: javascript, sitecore, google-custom-search

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the Google Custom Search I'm setting up on this site I have is not working the way I need it to. What I want is for the results to display within a page, and while the search takes me to the page, the results appear in a popup window for some reason.

This is what I have:

```
    <script>
        (function () {
            var cx = '[hidden]';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
    </script>

<gcse:searchbox-only linktarget="_self" resultsUrl="/HomePage/Search-Results"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

I tried using _parent for linktarget, but that did not solve the issue, either. Is there a way to disable this Google Custom Search from opening results in pop-ups?

Answer (score 8):

Go to Google Custom Search **Control panel**. Select the *Search-engine* where you generated the Key & Code. Go to *Look and Feel*, from the sidebar. Change the *Layout* from 'Overlay'(Popup) to the desire style you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the image to do this -

Click on **Look and Feel** on the left hand side then choose whatever layout you need. After that click on **Save & Get Code**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the linktarget from _self to _parent.

```
<gcse:searchbox-only linktarget="_parent"
```

Comment: I did try that--I mentioned it in my post. It does not solve the issue, unfortunately.